# Split string and take only part of it (python)

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, list

### QUESTION

I have a list of strings, let's call it ***input_list***, and every string in this list is made of five words divided only by a "%" character, like

```
"<word1>%<word2>%<word3>%<word4>%<word5>"
```

My goal is, for every element of ***input_list*** to make a string made only by `<word3>` and `<word4>` divided by the "%" sign, like this `"<word3>%<word4>"`,  and create a new list made by these strings.
So for example, if:

```
input_list = ['the%quick%brown%fox%jumps', 'over%the%lazy%dog%and']
```

then the new list will look like this

```
new_list = ['brown%fox', 'lazy%dog']
```

### IMPORTANT NOTES AND POSSIBLE ANSWERS

- The length of each word is random, so I can't just use string slicing or guess in any way how `<word3>` and `<word4>` start.
- A possible way to answer this would the following, but I want to know if there is a better and maybe (computationally) faster way, without having to create a new variable (current_list) and/or without having to consider/split the whole string (maybe using regex?)

```
input_list = ['the%quick%brown%fox%jumps', 'over%the%lazy%dog%and']
new_list = []
for element in input_list:
    current_list = element.split('%')
    final_element = [current_list[2], current_list[3]]
    new_list.append(final_element)
```

### EDIT:

I tried to compare the running time of @Pac0 answer with the running time of @bb1 answer, and, with an input list of 100 strings, @Pac0 has a running time of 92.28286 seconds, @bb1 has a running time of 42.6106374  seconds. So I will consider @bb1 one as the answer.

Comment: @00 by doing that, i just create a string instead of a list, it doesn't answer the questions wrote in "Important notes and possible answer"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
new_list = ['%'.join(w.split('%')[2:4]) for w in input_list]
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use a regular expression (regex) with a capture group:

```
import re

pattern = re.compile('[^%]*%[^%]*%([^%]*%[^%]*)%[^%]*')
input_list = ['the%quick%brown%fox%jumps', 'over%the%lazy%dog%and']

result = [pattern.search(s).group(1) for s in input_list]
print(result)
```

Note: the "compile" part is not strictly needed, but can help performance if you have a lot of strings to process.

Answer (score 1):

How about this?

```
input_list = ['the%quick%brown%fox%jumps', 'over%the%lazy%dog%and']
new_list = ['%'.join(x.split('%')[2:4]) for x in input_list]
print (new_list)
```

Output

```
['brown%fox', 'lazy%dog']
```